# How to identify the distribution of my data in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 20 measured data (actual test data).
And I would like to fine best distribution fitting for my data.
But I have some difficulties in python codling.

Here is my code. Please give me some advice to fix python code.

```
import numpy as np
from distfit import distfit
dist = distfit(todf=True)
X = [0.024683122, 0.242804512, 0.293910638, 0.298939727, 0.46083702, 1.068388009, 3.175447843, 4.165901528, 4.622206391, 5.030523381, 5.608041988, 5.672603047, 7.269741854, 7.537728098, 7.706391921, 13.64390375, 22.3135421, 25.48884842, 40.6591376, 51.45319478]
result = dist.fit_transform(X)
```

I am trying to find my data's best distribution fitting (ex. normal, lognormal, gamma, beta...)

Comment: you should provide `fit_transform` with a numpy array: `X=np.array([...])`

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind answer. It is really helpful for me!! (^^)